# Yii - Update field

Tags: php, sql, database, yii, frameworks

I have a template that corresponds to a table in the database and I need a form to edit only one field of that table, this table is made up of two primary keys.

For example, I have a table with 3 attributes, ID, ID2, and Name (Both ID and ID2 are primary keys). When I enter a user profile, I want it to fetch both ID's and only change the name field. What do I need to do?

I've already tried to create a form in the views where I want it to appear, and a function in the template that fetches the ID's from the user I'm searching. I can see the 'Name' field of that user, but I can not edit it.

Comment: Can you post your code also ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly your problem. But for fetching list of `primary key`, you can use `$yourModelInstance->primaryKey()`.

And about the `name` field to be updatable, you must specified `rules` for it in your `model::rules` function. Yii2 check for input rules before saving data as yii2 instructions. Here's an example:

`in your Model class:`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name'], 'string'],
        [['your primary key 1', 'your primary key 2'], 'int'],
    ];
}
```